# Token endpoint with AllowInsecureHttp=false still accepting http requests

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, jwt, access-token

Hope anyone can help me with the following highly frustrating problem.

I have .NET WebApi which I secured with jwt authentication. In setting up the `OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions`-object I set the property `AllowInsecureHttp` for my token end point to `false`. Running my API locally on IISExpress and testing it with Postman works like a charm. If I set the property to `true` and ask for a token on my end point it works, if I set it to `false` I get a `404` as expected. But when I publish the API to my production environment (Windows 2012/IIS8) and set the property to `false`, I can get a token over both https *and* http. It just doesn't seem to listen to the property.

I run the API as an application with alias Api under a domain with just one https-binding. I use the following helper base class for my API's:

```
public class BaseWebApi<TDerivedOAuthProvider> where TDerivedOAuthProvider : BaseOAuthProvider, new()
{
    public BaseWebApi(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
        config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
        config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalBearer));

        ConfigureOAuth(app);

        WebApiConfig.Register(config);
        app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        app.UseWebApi(config);
    }

    private static void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var allowInsecureHttp = Convert.ToBoolean(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["jwt::allowInsecureHttp"].ToString());
        var issuer = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["jwt::issuer"].ToString();
        var secret = TextEncodings.Base64Url.Decode(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["jwt::secret"].ToString());
        var clients = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["jwt::clients"].ToString().Split(new char[] { ',' });

        OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
        {
            AllowInsecureHttp = allowInsecureHttp,
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalBearer,
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10),
            Provider = new TDerivedOAuthProvider(),
            RefreshTokenProvider = new BaseRefreshTokenProvider(),
            AccessTokenFormat = new BaseJwtFormat(issuer),
        };

        // OAuth 2.0 Bearer Access Token Generation
        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);

        // Api controllers with an [Authorize] attribute will be validated with JWT
        app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalBearer,
            AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
            AllowedAudiences = clients,
            IssuerSecurityTokenProviders = new IIssuerSecurityTokenProvider[]
            {
                new SymmetricKeyIssuerSecurityTokenProvider(issuer, secret)
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Variables `allowInsecureHttp`, `issuer`, `secret` and `clients` are filled from a configuration file. Setting the value for `allowInsecureHttp` hardcoded to `false` or `true` does not change anything. This base class is then instantiated by my actual API which (next to the actual API functions) also provides a `CustomOAuthProvider` class handling the actual implementation of the credential checking for this particular API:

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(MyCustomAPI.Startup))]
namespace MyCustomAPI.API
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            BaseWebApi<CustomOAuthProvider> webApi = new BaseWebApi<CustomOAuthProvider>(app);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope anyone can point me in the right direction. Set aside this issue the API itself is working flawlessly, but I really want to force SSL on my production tokens.

Cheers,
Nyquist

Answer (score 0):

For anyone ever encountering the same issue. Figured it out eventually. Worked like a charm, but the HSTS policy on the domain I configured my virtual application redirected all http Postman traffic automatically to https. Installed the application on a simple domain without SSL and on that domain SSL was perfectly enforced. *sigh* :)